# Error on join pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to create a dataframe with a large number of stocks that I will eventually send to a MySQL database. I need to take all of the individual dataframes and join them together keeping their name and dates unique The problem I'm having currently is that the join portion of the code is throwing an error, I have tried a merge instead but doing that loses the name values for each dataframe and therefore doesn't suit my needs. I have also looked into using a panel instead but the I read that the .to_sql function is for dataframes only. Any help would be appreciated.

```
exchList =['A','AA','AAL','AAP','AAPL','ABBV','ABC','ABT','ACN','ADBE','ADI','ADM','ADP','ADS','ADSK','AEE','AEP']
main_df = pd.DataFrame()
start = datetime.datetime(2000,1,1)
end =  datetime.date.today()



for ticker in exchList:
   df = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo",start, end)
   df.reset_index(level=df.index.names, inplace=True)
   if main_df.empty:
       main_df = df
   else:
       main_df = main_df.join(df)
```

The error is the following.

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bit more elegant way to do that - read data for all tickers in one step to `Pandas.Panel` and then [flatten](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.to_frame.html) that `Panel` to a `DataFrame`:

```
In [126]: p = web.DataReader(exchList, "yahoo",start, end)

In [129]: p.to_frame()
Out[129]:
                        Open        High         Low       Close       Volume   Adj Close
Date       minor
2000-01-03 A       78.749999   78.937500   67.374999   72.000003    4674300.0   46.106304
           AAPL   104.874997  112.499998  101.687501  111.937502  133949200.0    3.625643
           ABC     15.500000   15.750000   15.250000   15.562500    2784800.0    3.297376
           ABT     35.249948   35.999945   34.749947   34.999948   10635000.0    9.517434
           ADBE    67.250000   67.500000   64.250000   65.562500    7384400.0   16.274673
           ADI     93.500000   93.875000   88.000000   90.187500    3655600.0   32.584012
           ADM     11.999999   12.062499   11.875000   11.999999     984600.0    7.798824
           ADP     53.499906   53.937406   51.937409   51.999911    2698800.0   28.858381
           ADSK    34.000000   34.625000   32.125000   33.375000    2845600.0    8.052905
           AEE     32.562500   32.625000   31.562500   32.312500     700800.0   13.102718
...                      ...         ...         ...         ...          ...         ...
2017-02-23 ABT     45.029999   45.509998   44.849998   45.400002    9389100.0   45.400002
           ACN    122.589996  122.709999  121.730003  122.480003    1428000.0  122.480003
           ADBE   120.099998  120.150002  118.029999  118.830002    2381700.0  118.830002
           ADI     82.150002   82.160004   81.029999   81.610001    2277500.0   81.610001
           ADM     44.799999   45.270000   44.490002   45.090000    3256200.0   45.090000
           ADP    100.790001  101.779999  100.489998  101.639999    1459300.0  101.639999
           ADS    240.589996  243.520004  239.279999  242.419998     650800.0  242.419998
           ADSK    86.690002   87.370003   85.919998   87.099998    1368000.0   87.099998
           AEE     54.230000   54.270000   53.689999   54.070000    1438100.0   54.070000
           AEP     65.550003   66.089996   65.309998   66.010002    2272900.0   66.010002

[63153 rows x 6 columns]
```

you may also want to reset the multi-index:

```
In [130]: p.to_frame().reset_index()
Out[130]:
            Date minor        Open        High         Low       Close       Volume   Adj Close
0     2000-01-03     A   78.749999   78.937500   67.374999   72.000003    4674300.0   46.106304
1     2000-01-03  AAPL  104.874997  112.499998  101.687501  111.937502  133949200.0    3.625643
2     2000-01-03   ABC   15.500000   15.750000   15.250000   15.562500    2784800.0    3.297376
3     2000-01-03   ABT   35.249948   35.999945   34.749947   34.999948   10635000.0    9.517434
4     2000-01-03  ADBE   67.250000   67.500000   64.250000   65.562500    7384400.0   16.274673
5     2000-01-03   ADI   93.500000   93.875000   88.000000   90.187500    3655600.0   32.584012
6     2000-01-03   ADM   11.999999   12.062499   11.875000   11.999999     984600.0    7.798824
7     2000-01-03   ADP   53.499906   53.937406   51.937409   51.999911    2698800.0   28.858381
8     2000-01-03  ADSK   34.000000   34.625000   32.125000   33.375000    2845600.0    8.052905
9     2000-01-03   AEE   32.562500   32.625000   31.562500   32.312500     700800.0   13.102718
...          ...   ...         ...         ...         ...         ...          ...         ...
63143 2017-02-23   ABT   45.029999   45.509998   44.849998   45.400002    9389100.0   45.400002
63144 2017-02-23   ACN  122.589996  122.709999  121.730003  122.480003    1428000.0  122.480003
63145 2017-02-23  ADBE  120.099998  120.150002  118.029999  118.830002    2381700.0  118.830002
63146 2017-02-23   ADI   82.150002   82.160004   81.029999   81.610001    2277500.0   81.610001
63147 2017-02-23   ADM   44.799999   45.270000   44.490002   45.090000    3256200.0   45.090000
63148 2017-02-23   ADP  100.790001  101.779999  100.489998  101.639999    1459300.0  101.639999
63149 2017-02-23   ADS  240.589996  243.520004  239.279999  242.419998     650800.0  242.419998
63150 2017-02-23  ADSK   86.690002   87.370003   85.919998   87.099998    1368000.0   87.099998
63151 2017-02-23   AEE   54.230000   54.270000   53.689999   54.070000    1438100.0   54.070000
63152 2017-02-23   AEP   65.550003   66.089996   65.309998   66.010002    2272900.0   66.010002

[63153 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @user3170242, glad i could help :-) Thanks for  accepting an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the two dataframes that you are trying to join have column names in common. In order to correctly join the two, you need to specify the full join method `DataFrame.join(other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='', sort=False)`

So you need to specify a left suffix or a right suffix. For example for

```
df1.columns = ['A','B']
df2.columns = ['B','C']
```

when you join the two together, if you aren't joining on 'B', then you need to specify a suffix to add to either of the dataframes' column names in order to not have duplicate column names in the joined dataframe

[See here for the join method documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to concatenate the tables together, not join them.  To do this change the code to the following.

```
   if main_df.empty:
       main_df = df
   else:
       main_df = pd.concate([main_df,df])
```

A better way would be to have a list of all the frames then concate them at the end.

```
import pandas as pd
l_dfs = list()
for ticker in exchList:
   df = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo",start, end)
   df.reset_index(level=df.index.names, inplace=True)
   l_dfs.append(df)
df = pd.concate(l_dfs)
```